# Custom backend parse body in a better way

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm creating a custom backend (build on top of the http module) for fun. But I stumbled upon a problem with getting/parsing the body. I have solved it, but it still isn't what I am looking for. This is what I have now:

```
this.body = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let _d;
        req.on('data', (chunk) => {
            _d += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', () => {
            if(_d === undefined) return resolve(null);
            resolve(JSON.parse(_d.replace('undefined', '')));
        });

        req.on('error', (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
```

I have tried this without using promises but then the body will be undefined. Every time I want to access body I have to do this:

```
let body = req.body.then(value => {return value});
```

Is there a better way to do this.

Thank you for your time.

request.js:

```
const {IncomingMessage} = require('http');
const url = require('url');

class Request {
    /**
     * @param {IncomingMessage} req 
     */
    constructor(req) {
        /**
         * @type {IncomingMessage}
         */
        this.http = req;

        /**
         * @type {Promise<{}>}
         * @returns {{}}
         */
        this.body = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let _d;
            req.on('data', (chunk) => {
                _d += chunk;
            });

            req.on('end', () => {
                if(_d === undefined) return resolve(null);
                resolve(JSON.parse(_d.replace('undefined', '')));
            });

            req.on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }
    
    /**
     * Get query
     * @returns {import('querystring').ParsedUrlQuery}
     */
    get query() {
        return url.parse(this.http.url, true).query;
    }
}

/**
 * Get the custom request
 * @param {IncomingMessage} req
 * @returns {Request}
 */
 function getReq(req) {
    return new Request(req);
}

module.exports = {
    Request,
    getReq
}
```

backend.js:

```
const {Path} = require('./routes');
const {getReq, Request} = require('./request');
const {getRes, Response} = require('./response');
const {Server} = require('http');

class App {
    constructor() {
        this.http = require('http');

        /**
         * @type {Array<Path>}
         * @private
         */
        this.urls = []

        /**
         * @type {Server}
         * @private
         */
        this.server = new this.http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
            for(var i = 0; i < this.urls.length; i++) {
                /**
                 * @type {Path}
                 */
                let path = this.urls[i];

                if((path.url === req.url && path.method === req.method) || (path.url === "*" && path.method === req.method)) {
                    path.callback(getReq(req), getRes(res));
                    return;
                }

                if(path.method === 'ALL' && (path.url === req.url || path.url === "*")) {
                    path.callback(getReq(req), getRes(res));
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * @callback Callback
     * @param {Request} req
     * @param {Response} res
     */

    /**
     * Listen for GET requests
     * @param {String} url 
     * @param {Callback} callback
     */
    get(url, callback) {
        this.urls.push(new Path('GET', url, callback));
    }

    /**
     * Listen for POST requests
     * @param {String} url 
     * @param {Callback} callback
     */
    post(url, callback) {
        this.urls.push(new Path('POST', url, callback));
    }
    
    /**
     * Listen for all requests
     * @param {String} url 
     * @param {Callback} callback
     */
    all(url, callback) {
        this.urls.push(new Path('ALL', url, callback));
    }

    /**
     * Start the server
     * @param {Number} port 
     * @param {Function} callback
     */
    listen(port, callback = () => {}) {
        this.server.listen(port);
        callback();
    }

    /**
     * Add middleware
     * @param {Callback} callback
     */
    middleware(callback) {
        this.urls.push(new Path('ALL', '*', callback));
    }
}

/**
 * Create the app
 * @returns {App}
*/
function createServer() {
    return new App();
}

module.exports = createServer;
```

Comment: No, there's no better way to do this, if you want to use the parsed body you'll have to wait for it to arrive. Of course there are many ways to avoid duplicate code for waiting, e.g. using a handler chain like in *express*, but you haven't shown the structure of your http server code yet.

Comment: I'll add the code.

Comment: Any reason you're not using express? It provides body-parsers that already implement this.

Comment: I had nothing to do so i started making this for fun to challenge myself. Normally when I make a website, I use express.

Comment: @Burperino Ah, thanks. So if you don't want to write promise code (`const body = await req.body;`) in every of those path handlers, you need to change the `path.callback(getReq(req), getRes(res));` line(s) so that it waits for the body before calling `callback` and passes in a request object with the promise result as the `.body`.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time and dedication.